A closed set with empty interior
How do I prove that the set
$L_n = \{f \in C([0, 1]), \exists \, x_0 \text{ such that } \forall \, x \in [0, 1], |f(x) - f(x_0)| \leq n|x - x_0|\}$
is closed with empty interior?  Furthermore, how do I show that $C([0, 1]) \setminus \cup_n L_n$ is of second category and it is made of nowhere differentiable functions.
This is my idea:
The set $L_n = \{f \in C([0, 1]) \mid \exists \, x_0 \in [0, 1], \forall \, x \in [0, 1], |f(x) - f(x_0)| \leq n|x - x_0|\}$ is closed because it is defined by a Lipschitz condition, and uniform limits of functions satisfying this condition also satisfy it. Specifically, if a sequence ({f_k} \subset L_n) converges uniformly to $f$, the associated points $\{x_k\}$ converge (up to a subsequence) to some $x_0$, and the uniform convergence ensures that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| \leq n|x - x_0|$, proving $f \in L_n$. How do I conclude the rest?
I would appreciate any helpful suggestions, ideas, or comments.

"$C([0, 1]) \cup \cup_n L_n$ is of second category and it is made of nowhere differentiable functions": do you mean $\cup_n L_n$ is of second category and its complement is made of nowhere differentiable functions?

Yes. Thank you. I have now edited the post. Could you kindly help?

A hint on the proof of $\text{int }L_n=\emptyset$: It suffices to prove the complement of $L_n$ is dense. For each $f\in C[0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$, use uniform continuity to partition $[0,1]$ into small intervals, on each of which the change of $f$ is small. For each small interval $[u,v]$, construct $\psi\in C[u,v]\setminus L_n$ by gluing two lines respectively passing $(u,f(u))$ and $(v,f(v))$, with slope $n+1$ and $-(n+1)$.

You didn't completely fix the statement: there remains a strange $C([0, 1]) \cup \cup_n L_n$. This is the only comment I am able to do, I do not master this subject.

I have now reedited the post. Thanks for your comment.
